# Are there 4D spacetime not described by GR?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, spacetime-dimensions, equivalence-principle

I heard the EFE is specifically for 4 spacetime dimensions. Does it mean whenever there are 4 spacetime dimensions, there is automatically GR?  In other words, are there 4D worlds or spacetime that are not described by GR? Kindly enumerate them if there is.

Comment: *I heard the EFE is specifically for 4 dimensions.* That’s not true. It makes sense in other dimensions.

Comment: Any reference how to apply EFE in other dimensions more than 4?

Comment: Literally ANY text on GR is a reference. I don’t know where you could have possibly read that the EFE applies only to 4 dimensions. Whichever book you read it in, throw it away right now.

Comment: What do you mean by spacetime exactly? Are you asking if there are relations on 4-coordinates that aren't a solution to the einstein field equations?

Comment: *what mathematically speaking do you mean by spacetime, is what I meant to ask

Comment: What i originally meant was.. whenever there are 3 dimensions of space + 1 time. Does GR automatically result? What would happen if just for sake of discussion, our universe were not described by GR. Does it mean feather and iron core won't fall at same rate in vacuum? I just read about Nordstrome below and asking of other formulations of 4D that doesn't use GR.

Answer (score 3):

The theory of general relativity is a metric theory of gravity, with a Lorentzian metric (ie a metric with signature $-+++$). This means that any manifold with such a metric can be analyzed using the theory of general relativity.

As far as topology goes, there are a few requirements for this to be the case. Most famously, the manifold has to be paracompact and admit a line element over the entire manifold. This means that there are a variety of manifolds in 4 dimensions which cannot be spacetimes. In particular, if it is compact and the Euler characteristic isn't zero, then there is no spacetime you can put on it. This means that, for instance, $S^4$, $S^2 \times S^2$, or $S^2 \times G_2$ ($G_2$ the surface of genus 2) cannot be spacetimes.

Considering the paracompact condition, we also can't have any spacetimes that are "long". Given the long line $\mathbb{L}$, we can't use $\mathbb{L}^4$, or any products involving the long line, or any more exotic ones like products involving the Prüfer manifold, can be spacetimes.

Answer (score 1):

The external field effect (EFE) is about whether the gravitational force of the external gravity sources can be effectively cancelled out (via equivalence principle) by changing to the free-fall reference frame.

This hinges on the fact that the Einstein field equation of gravity is linear in the Riemann curvature tensor $R$ (for brevity I omitted the indices and I also omitted the technicality of differences between Einstein tensor and Riemann curvature tensor). In the weak field limit, the linearity is reflected in the field equation:
$$
\nabla^2 g_{00} = -\kappa \rho
$$
where the relation between $\nabla^2g_{00}$ ($g_{00}$ is the $00$th component of the metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$) and mass density $\rho$ is linear.

The linearity above means that the gravity effects of different sources can be linearly added. This in turn implies that the gravity effects from external sources can be linearly subtracted by changing to the free-fall reference frame. In other words, in the free-fall frame with reference to the external gravitational sources, you can safely study the gravitational forces from the internal gravitational sources as if the external gravitational sources do not exist.

However, **Einstein's GR is NOT the only allowable (diffeomorphism invariant) theory of gravity in 3+1 dimensional space-time.** In the effective field theory framework, Einstein's GR is only the first order term $R$ in the towering series of terms proportional to higher powers of Riemann curvature tensor:
$$
R^0 + R + R^2 + R^3 + ...
$$
where cosmological constant is the zeroth order term $R^0$. All the non-Einstein terms are allowable in the gravitational equation.

With these higher order non-linear terms, the gravity from different sources are no longer linearly addable. Therefore, the gravitational force of the external gravity sources can NOT be linearly subtracted (via equivalence principle) by changing to the free-fall reference frame.

**In summary, EFE depends on whether the field equation is linear or non-linear. Space-time dimension, on the other hand, does not play a major role.** Gravity in higher dimension just falls off at a faster rate. That's all. For example, $\sim 1/r^2$ in 3+1 dimension,  vs. $\sim 1/r^3$ in 4+1 dimension.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So (1) Do the EFE generalize to more than 3+1 dimensions ? (2) What is the equivalent of Newtonian gravity in more than 3 spatial dimensions. (3) Can the EFE for n + 1 dimensions ($n>3) be made consistent with the corresponding "Newtonian gravity". (4) is it true the EFE of GR is specifically for 4 dimensions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No. [Nordström's theory of gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nordstr%C3%B6m%27s_theory_of_gravitation) was an early competitor to GR and is an equally self-consistent theory in 4 dimensions.

According to [*Nordstrom's scalar theory of gravity and the equivalence principle*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.4608) (2011) by Nathalie Deruelle, it is the only theory of gravity with GR to obey the [strong equivalence principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle#The_strong_equivalence_principle).

Comment: If there is 3d space plus 1d time. Will GR come out naturally?  If not. How would the world be like if say equivalence principle was not true?

Comment: @Samzun Like I said, Nordström's theory works just as well as GR in 3+1 dimensions. So it can't be the case that 3+1 dimensions requires GR.

Regarding the equivalence principle: There are multiple versions of it, and they differ in subtle ways. See the Wikipedia article I linked to, especially the subsection titled "Tests of the strong equivalence principle". See also the [Nordtvedt effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nordtvedt_effect).